PHP-FPM and Apache - setting SCRIPT_NAME
So far as I can tell, a simple installation of Apache and PHP-FPM (the versions supplied in the Debian 12 repository) results in different values for $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] from when Apache mod_php is used. This is in a context where the URL is not pointing to a script, but has been constructed to be user (and perhaps search engine) friendly. The URL is switched to index.php using mod_rewrite.
The behaviour can be verified without the use of any software application. This can be done by creating one configuration with PHP-FPM and one with mod_php, enabling mod_rewrite in both cases and configuring it with:
## The following 3 lines provide standard SEF rewrite
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [L]

Install an index.php file that contains only:
<?php var_dump($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])

and note the different behaviour between the two environments when presented with e.g. https://example.com/heading/article.
Specifically, a URL such as https://example.com/heading/article results in SCRIPT_NAME being set to "/heading/article" with PHP-FPM. When mod_php is used SCRIPT_NAME is empty. (If a different rewrite were used, mod_php would place the directory preceding the name of the PHP file in SCRIPT_NAME).
The behaviour is not affected by different settings of cgi.fix_pathinfo in php.ini.
Some software fails to work in the PHP-FPM situation, although it works correctly with mod_php, on account of the SCRIPT_NAME setting.
Is there a way to configure PHP-FPM so as to overcome this problem? I'm aware that it is possible to overcome the issue with auto_prepend_file in php.ini but that seems like a hack and may not work with all software.

Some software fails to work in the PHP-FPM situation, although it works correctly with mod_php. Is there a way to configure PHP-FPM so as to overcome this problem?...nobody can tell you anything about it with that level of detail. Pick a specific issue and [edit] your question to provide a clear description of the problem and a [mre] of that issue. See also [ask]. You start by asking about the rewrites, although without providing a fully worked example, but then seem to also veer off into attempting to ask about other, unspecified problems. The question needs a clearer focus. Thanks.

I was assuming that most people are familiar with the widely used technique of creating URLs that do not actually point to a file... we are. I wanted to focus on the specific issue that a URL of this kind seems to be treated differently by mod_php and PHP-FPM...ok, but then you need to provide a worked example of a rule that isn't working as expected. This site is about solving programming problems, and that requires at least some usable, reproducible evidence. Then someone can take your example and try it for themselves, knowing that we're talking about exactly the same thing you are

So rather than writing a long apology, which we don't need, you should edit your question to provide relevant example of sample URLs, and your rewrite rule, and clear description of the behaviour of the system in each different configuration, compared to what you expected. Then we can crack on with helping you. Thanks.

The apology was only one sentence. The rest was clarification. I was imagining that someone would recognise the issue from their knowledge of PHP implementations. Perhaps I was mistaken.Yes, mod_rewrite is used in exactly the same way in both cases. I will experiment with cgi_pathinfo but have seen reports that it does not resolve this issue.

I have now confirmed that setting cgi.fix_pathinfo to either 0 or 1 makes no difference to the problem.

I was imagining that someone would recognise the issue from their knowledge of PHP implementations...and they might. But it will be a lot easier to and reproduce the problem if everyone is using the exact same settings and code as you are.

I have now confirmed that setting cgi.fix_pathinfo to either 0 or 1 makes no difference to the problem...that info needs to be in your question then, not in the comments. Thanks.

Remember this isn't just a troubleshooting service, we're trying to build a repo of questions and answers which will have long-term value. So the question needs to contain as much detail as possible, in order to carry that value for future readers - they are just as much the audience for any answers as you are personally.

"Some software fails to work" - are these open source/public things that you can reference? Do they note this in their documentation anywhere?

My particular concern is Joomla. The documentation is unhelpful. There is a configuration option called live_site that can be set to the site URL. If it is set, there is no problem.  But if it is not set, a standard PHP-FPM installation does not work for the reasons given. The concern is that Joomla forums are packed with statements that live_site should not be used, and is not needed, and should be removed in future releases. Also, some possible claims that the update process can go wrong if live_site is set. But other software could be affected.
